# How can I replace "\-" to "- " in the url with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have text:

`https://youtu.be/iOA7NUI\-9Xhwvideo\-one\-`

I need to replace `\-` to `-` with JS, so i get:

`https://youtu.be/iOA7NUI-9Xhwvideo-one-`

Comment: For now this is best solution `return text.replace(/(\S)(\\)(-)(\S)/g, "$1$3$4");`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/(^|[^ ])\\-($|[^ ])/g` by `$1-$2`.

`$1` refers to the first capturing group (same for `$2`).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ugNU8MKL7hu4QgFe)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `replace` method and use below regex to match `\-` only that contains in URL. I used the logic of space that is not there in URL.

```
\\-(?=\S)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aD6uX1/1)

Pattern explanation:

```
  \\                       '\'
  -                        '-'
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: what if the dash was at the end of the url/word?

Comment: @OGHaza add `$` in pattern `\\-(?=\S|$)`. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aD6uX1/2)

Comment: I meant like this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aD6uX1/3), but OPs requirements don't make it clear what is necessary. Clearly your original answer solves the problem for his given example.

Comment: @OGHaza thanks for your time and testing but there are lots of permutation and combination. I need more info about the rules. Need to verify with OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace javascript method!

```
    text = text.replace('\-', '-');
```

Comment: don't you think that it will replace all `-` where is OP is looking for url only.